# Moving physical disk from local computer to network server

Tags: debian, permissions, nfs, file-sharing

In my Debian GNU/Linux based workstation I have a big nice disk (3TB), apart from my ssd where the OS is installed.

I recently got an intel nuci5 and set it up as a home server, together with my Gigabit Ethernet I am able to transfer files between the server and the workstation at full speed (~120Mbyte/sec).

What I would like to do is move the disk from my workstation to my server, set up an nfs-share on the server, mount the disk on my workstation and have everything still working like it was when the disk was local.

What I don't know is how to set up `/etc/exports` and `/etc/fstab` on the server and `/etc/fstab` on the local machine for this to work. I know the basics for these files but I would like some help to get the correct parameters from start.

Here is what I have now on my workstation.

```
mount | grep green
/dev/sdc1 on /mnt/green type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
cat /etc/fstab | grep nuci5
nuci5:/media/share /mnt/nuci5 nfs defaults 0 0
nuci5:/mnt/extra  /mnt/nuci5-extra nfs defaults 0 0
ls -lah /mnt/ | grep green
drwxr-xr-x 11 mihaly mihaly  4,0K okt  9 20:56 green
cat /etc/passwd | grep mihaly
mihaly:x:1000:1000:Mihaly Bak,,,:/home/mihaly:/bin/bash
```

On my server:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep mihaly
mihaly:x:1000:1000:Mihaly Bak,,,:/home/mihaly:/bin/bash
cat /etc/exports
/media/share 192.168.1.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/media/share 192.168.1.*(ro,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,all_squash)
/mnt/extra/ 192.168.1.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

**192.168.1.2** is the IP of my workstation.

Being that I have the same uid on both machines for my user and my user already owns all the files this should be rather easy, if I have understood anything correctly about nfs and linux permissions.

Comment: This looks good, can you try it out and let us know if something doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/etc/exports` you need to replace the 192.168.1.* with 192.168.1.0/24, you can only use wildcards in hostnames.

You also need to create the mountpoints on the client system, you only show the current mountpoint `/mnt/green`; `/mnt/nuci5` and `/mnt/nuci5-extra` must also exist. Maybe they do, but you filtered those out in that case.

Beyond that it should work. Personally I use `async` in `/etc/exports` because I'm not that worried about possible data loss and more interested in speed. Of course you need to make your own decision about that. I also use mount options `soft,intr` because I don't want things to hang indefinitely if the NFS server is not reachable; again, make your own decision about that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I changed 192.168.1.* to 192.168.1.0/24. I was already using the 192.168.1.* combination and it worked on both devices that connect to the server, but 0/24 seams to work just as well. I will add the additional mount point for the new share, unfortunately I do not have the hardware cabinet to connect the disk to the server. Will hopefully be able to acquire it tomorrow and be able to try it out.

Comment: It worked out good.

However I got a new notes in the dmesg log.

On the server

[2413879.384972] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
[2413879.385021] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period

On my client

[   21.731313] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
[   21.731464] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net ffffffff81887000)
[  775.492835] NFS: v4 server nuci5 does not accept raw uid/gids. Reenabling the idmapper